# Why is Figma not exporting all my pages?

Tags: figma, wireframing

I have two pages in my Figma project.

I then hit the menu > File > Export Pages as PDF.

The resulting PDF only has a single page added to it, and the other is missing. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in Figma as “Export Pages as PDF”. There is, however, an option to export all **frames** to PDF. All frames that you want to export should be on the same page, this will give you a multi-page PDF.

[image: Figma screenshot: Main menu → File → Export frames to PDF]

Note that the resulting PDF would probably be quite large, so I recommend using other apps, online converters or Figma plugins to reduce the file size.